# UISplitViewController with best behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller

Until now, I used UISplitViewController with static UITableView and segues.

[here a little exemple of my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYle9.png)

(I have multiple DetailViewControllers)

But not working like I want.

I want UISplitViewController like iOS Settings app & Notes app, that is to say, I don't want re-load my UIViewController when I selected it (like Notes app). And if I selected the actually UIViewController embedded in a UINavigationController, I want automatically get a "popToRootViewController" totally like iOS Settings app.

I've done a lot of research and couldn't really figure out how to set this up.

I'm French and not very good in English so please excuse me if I'm not very clear.

Thank you.